# Is there a function to check whether an ID you want to use for an entity is available?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, python-2.7

I think I read something about a function appengine has that can tell whether an ID / key you want to use for an entity is available, or if there was a function to get an available ID to choose. App engine team said also that we should set the ID when the entity is created and not change it. But in practice we can just copy everything to a new entity with the new ID?

Thanks!

### Update

I think the function I'm looking for is allocateIDs from the docs:
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/functions.html

Comment: Why do you think you want that?  Why do you want a particular ID?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I was asked if there was a way to for instance make the ID 2002 since the system I'm making relies on IDs rather than emails for logging in. I think it's not ideal but it is the spec. I can imagine a case when if you accidentally delete user 2002 you would want to recreate the user with the same ID since the user has that ID to log himself in.

Comment: Then don't delete users but simply disable them :) (Not helpful in answering your question, I know.)

Comment: @Thomas I know but during testing I got some bad test data so I had to remove a complete user entity even though I didn't want to. It seemed to have saved data in latin-1 and my app was using unicode so I wanted to start over with fresh data that was all unicode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reserve one or more IDs, use allocate_ids(). To check whether an ID is already taken, just construct a Key for it using Key.from_path(kind, id) and try to db.get() it.  Also note that IDs for keys with a parent are taken from separate pools and are only unique among keys with the same parent.

Comment: Thanks! Specifically I'm going to try to fulfil a requirement that user IDs don't get longer than 7 positions for a ssmall app and user IDs already are 5 positions like 20022 is an ID even though there are only 10 user entities or so in the datastore. My client specifically wanted a system where users log in with their IDs instead of usernames so I'm trying to fulfil that requirement even though I don't know if I like it.

Comment: @NickRosencrantz There's not much you can do about how the datastore allocates IDs. How are you planning to generate the numbers you pass to `allocate_ids`? I'd personally bend all my efforts to trying to convince the customer not to do this - for that matter, don't use usernames at all - use email addresses!

Answer (score 1):

On the page describing [transactions](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/transactions.html), a use case is presented where the entity in question, a `SalesAccount` is updated, or if the account doesn't exist, it is created instead.  The technique is to just try to load the entity with the given key; and if it returns nothing, create it.  It's important to do this inside a transaction to avoid the situation where two users are both racing for the same key, and both see that it doesn't exist (and both try to create it).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand my scenario is not ideal but I needed a way to assign ID to new entities.